Find out information about an ODE without actually computing the solution
I'm taking a course on ODEs, and I'm currently on the chapter about initial value problems. In this chapter, we try to find out information about the solutions of the problem
\begin{cases}
    x'(t) = f(t, x(t)), \\
    x(t_0) = \xi
\end{cases}
without actually solving it, things like how big the maximal domain of the solutions is, etc.
In the particular problem I'm looking for help with, we are given the aforementioned equation with
\begin{equation}
f(t, x) = \frac{x+t}{t-2}
\end{equation}
and $t_0 = 0$. We have to make conclusions about the domain of the maximal solutions, when the solutions are increasing or decreasing...
Because $f \in C^{1}((-\infty, 2) \times \mathbb{R})$, we know solutions are defined on $(-\infty, 2)$. Also, analysing the sign of $f$, we know a solution $x$ will be increasing under the line $x + t = 0$, and it will be decreasing above it. Therefore, the solution should oscillate around this line.
All that's left to work out is how the solution will behave when $t \to 2^-$. Facing it, I think the possible solutions are: either the limit $\lim_{t \to 2^-} x(t)$ exists or it doesn't (duh).
If the limit exists, the two options are: the oscillation pulling the solution towards the line is not strong enough and it dies somewhere else (limit $\neq -2$), or this very pull makes it so that the limit is indeed $-2$. It doesn't seem feasible that the pull isn't strong enough, because if $x(t) + t$ isn't very small, $x'(t) = f(t, x(t))$ should skyrocket given that the denominator is going to $0$. I have been able to prove that this isn't the case: If I assume $\lim_{t \to 2^-} x(t) = l \neq -2$, because the limit exists, there is an interval to the left of $2$, $(a, 2)$, where $x(t)$ is strictly in one of the two sides of the line $x + t = 0$, so it is monotonous. For example, take $l > 2$. Then
\begin{equation}
x'(t) = \frac{x + t}{t - 2} < \frac{l + t}{t - 2} \; \; \forall t \in (a, 2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x(t) - x(a) = \int_a^t x'(u) \; du < \int_a^t \frac{l + u}{u - 2} \; du,
\end{equation}
but if you do the calculation it is easy to see that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to 2^-} \int_a^t \frac{l + u}{u - 2} \; du = -\infty \Longrightarrow \lim_{t \to 2^-} x(t) = -\infty,
\end{equation}
so we've arrived at a contradiction.
I haven't been able to figure out whether the limit indeed exists. In my head, I was considering the possibilities that the oscillations would be of smaller and smaller magnitudes and end up in $-2$, or it would be like $\sin(1/x)$ and keep oscillating with no limit. However, I've plotted some solutions using Mathematica, and it turns out that they don't actually oscillate around the line, I guess because for most values of t both the numerator and the denominator are similar and so the plot is quite close to a line, and the solutions do tend to $-2$ when $t \to 2^-$. Do you know of some way to prove this fact?

That ODE can be solved explicitly. Is it against the rules?

You can easily see that $x''(t) = \tfrac{1}{t-2}$ by differentiating the ODE

For oscillations you need an at least second order DE. In first order the line $x+t=0$ is an asymptote and the approach has exponentially falling distance.

Thanks to @Hyperbolic PDE friend's comment, I was able to figure it out. We can easily compute
\begin{equation}
x''(t) = \frac{1}{t-2},
\end{equation}
and since it doesn't have any roots, $x'$ will have at most one root, so there is an interval $(a, 2)$ where $x$ is monotonous. Furthermore, it is straightforward to see that it is bounded by $-2$ from below if it is decreasing, and by $-2$ from above if it is increasing; so the limit indeed exists and the reasoning I gave in the question proves this limit is $-2$.
